# laravel db migrate getting error

Tags: laravel, dbmigrate

When I run `php artisan migrate`, I am getting an error like this:

```
In 2017_12_26_045926_create_table_articles.php line 41:

  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC), expecting ',' or  
   ')'
```

This is my **articles tables**:

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->integer('category_id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('content');
            $table->boolean('is_show')->default(false);
            $table->boolean('is_active')->default(false);
            $table->integer('page_showing')->default(0);
            $table->string('header_pic');
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();


          Schema::table('articles', function($table){
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('articles');
    }
}
```

I am adding foreign key for articles and comments, but the articles tables when migrate is giving errors like above. What's wrong?

Comment: This is not valid PHP. It's even telling you which line is not valid (which the rest of us can't see).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to alter table when you are creating the table to put foreigns.

```
Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned(); // Or $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
    $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
    $table->string('title');
    $table->text('content');
    $table->boolean('is_show')->default(0);
    $table->boolean('is_active')->default(0);
    $table->integer('page_showing')->default(0);
    $table->string('header_pic');
    $table->softDeletes();
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

However, you can do that correctly with this code

```
Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
    $table->string('title');
    $table->text('content');
    $table->boolean('is_show')->default(0);
    $table->boolean('is_active')->default(0);
    $table->integer('page_showing')->default(0);
    $table->string('header_pic');
    $table->softDeletes();
    $table->timestamps();

});
  Schema::table('articles', function($table){
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Comment: when i remove alter table ..thie error..
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL  
  : alter table `articles` add constraint `articles_user_id_foreign` foreign   
  key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delete cascade)

Comment: that is because you need to put `unsigned`
I'll modify my answer now

Comment: i am put unsigned on my articles tables,, but now the error is..
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid default val  
  ue for 'is_parent'
>
i put unsigned also in my coments table..

Comment: you must put `1` (true) or `0`(false) into a boolean default value
i edited again my code.
`is_parent ` field is into `coments` table? do this `$table->boolean('is_parent')->default(0);`

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you are using the schema class again which is missing the closing tag ")};" and there is no need to use Schema class again you can use the same object to add a foreign key to the table. 
Try the below code :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->integer('category_id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('content');
        $table->boolean('is_show')->default(false);
        $table->boolean('is_active')->default(false);
        $table->integer('page_showing')->default(0);
        $table->string('header_pic');
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('articles');
}
```

OR

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->integer('category_id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('content');
        $table->boolean('is_show')->default(false);
        $table->boolean('is_active')->default(false);
        $table->integer('page_showing')->default(0);
        $table->string('header_pic');
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->timestamps();


        Schema::table('articles', function($table){
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
        }); //closing Schema class tag
    });     //closing Schema class tag
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('articles');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the closure on `Schema::create`

```
Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->integer('category_id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('content');
            $table->boolean('is_show')->default(false);
            $table->boolean('is_active')->default(false);
            $table->integer('page_showing')->default(0);
            $table->string('header_pic');
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();
});
```